# Difference between CHANDI NAVASATHI MANTRAMALA and Durga Sapthasathi!

Tags: moksha, devi

The Sri Devi Mahatmyam, [Sri CHANDI NAVASATHI MANTRAMALA](http://navasathi.blogspot.com/)' restored by 'Sri Sri Sri Gopanandanatha' adheres to the principle of Sanathana Dharma and guides one to achieve 'Gnana' and eventually attains the goal of 'Moksha'.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPB_Cxk39X19puayq2RXsCvCkmtx7v-UM

Did anyone read [Sri CHANDI NAVASATHI MANTRAMALA](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.382828/mode/2up)?  If so, what are the differences  between CHANDI NAVASATHI MANTRAMALA and Durga Sapthasathi?

Comment: What differences are you looking for ? Sapta shati is 700 verses from markandeya purana. Navashati was restored from where?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi:    You can go through this [article](http://navasathi.blogspot.com/)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi: You can go through the [book here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.382828/mode/2up)

Comment: that would be more of opinion based question. What one thinks and what not. I personally don't follow it.

Comment: Question has been revised @RakeshJoshi